# Why is $\{1,-1,i,-i\}$ isomorphic to the cyclic group $C_4$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism

I'm reading the Wu-ki Tung's book Group Theory in Physics, where it is stated that the group $\{\pm 1, \pm i\}$ under the usual multiplication is isomorphic to the cyclic group of order $4$, $C_4$. If I understood correctly, the multiplication table for $C_4$ is
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
& I & A & B & C \\ \hline
I & I & A & B & C \\
A & A & B & C & I \\
B & B & C & I & A \\
C & C & I & A & B \\
\end{array}
$$
while the table for $\{1, -1, i, -i\} \equiv \{I,A,B,C\}$ is
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
& I & A & B & C \\ \hline
I & I & A & B & C \\
A & A & I & C & B \\
B & B & C & A & I \\
C & C & B & I & A \\
\end{array}
$$

Both tables are different and cannot be made equal by just relabeling the elements. Why are these groups isomorphic to each other?

Comment: Perhaps it is easier to notice that $\{1,-1,i,-i\}$ contains an element of order 4: $i^4=1$.

Comment: Even if the book is wrong, you shouldn't point out the mistakes. It's not wise to upset a Wu-ki.

Comment: The second should become the first by relabeling $I':=I$, $A':=A$, $B'=A$, $C'=C$, unless there is a mistake in the book which I don't think there is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cyclic group of order 4 is the abelian group $\{1,a,a^2,a^3\}$, and the other group is $\{1,i,i^2,i^3\}$ so the isomorphism is quite easy to see. In your question you've put $-1$ as the second element, which is probably what confused you.

Comment: Now I see the point, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

The order 2 element is $-1$, and the order 4 elements are $\pm i$. So if you let $B = -1$, $A = i$ and $C = -i$ in the second table you'll find the same table as above.

Answer (score 1):

Isomoprphisms send identity to identity and preserve elements' orders. So, defined $G:=\{1,-1,i,-i\}$, $C_4:=\{1,a,a^2,a^3\}$, and $\varphi\colon G\to C_4$ as a candidate isomorphism, necessarily:
\begin{alignat}{1}
\varphi(1) &:= 1 \\
\varphi(-1) &:= a^2 \\
\end{alignat}
As for $\pm i$, both of order $4$, in order to get a bijection we are left with:
\begin{alignat}{1}
\varphi(i) &:= a \\
\varphi(-i) &:= a^3 \\
\end{alignat}
or:
\begin{alignat}{1}
\varphi(i) &:= a^3 \\
\varphi(-i) &:= a \\
\end{alignat}
and both options lead indeed to an isomorphism. So, we have actually two of them.